# Internet Explorer Static GridView issues

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, gridview

I am having some really weird issues with my static GridView Header. The lines in IE aren't lining up properly; some of them do, and others do not. Can some one help me out? It works perfectly in Chrome, just not IE.

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

IE:
[image: IE]

Here is my relevant code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function MakeStaticHeader(gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter) {
                        var tbl = document.getElementById(gridId);
                        if (tbl) {
                            var DivHR = document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow');
                            var DivMC = document.getElementById('DivMainContent');
                            var DivFR = document.getElementById('DivFooterRow');

                            //*** Set divheaderRow Properties ****
                            DivHR.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
                            DivHR.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 50) + 'px';
                            DivHR.style.position = 'relative';
                            DivHR.style.top = '0px';
                            DivHR.style.left = (tbl.clientLeft-25) +'px';
                            DivHR.style.zIndex = '10';
                            DivHR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
                            DivHR.style.alignContent = 'center';

                            //*** Set divMainContent Properties ****
                            DivMC.style.width = width + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.height = height + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.position = 'relative';
                            DivMC.style.top = -headerHeight + 'px';
                            DivMC.style.zIndex = '1';
                            //****Copy Header in divHeaderRow****
                            DivHR.appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true));
                        }
                    }



                    function OnScrollDiv(Scrollablediv) {
                        document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
                        //if (document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft >= 300) {
                        //    document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = 300;
                        //}
                    }

                </script>
```

CSS

```
  html, body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

CSS Header Style

```
.GVFixedHeader
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: Green;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how IE renders a GridView. I would custom change my formating on one cell of the table, but that would mess with IE and change the default settings. Chrome would correctly identify that I only wanted to add style not change completely.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space: inital;");
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: left;");//THIS IS WHAT I ADDED + some altering of the width of the JS
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Make Inactive?";
                        }
                        if (i == 9)
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "Total Invoice YTD";
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space: normal;");
                        }
                        if (i == 13)
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space: normal;");
                        }
                    }
                    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space: nowrap;"); } //ALWAYS makes sure there is no wrapping of text
                }
```